# Why do I get the timeout warning?

Tags: customization, errors

I turned on debug mode in WordPress and the first request of the day I get this error:

Warning: http_request() [function.http-request]: Timeout was reached; Operation timed out after 1000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received (/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron) in /public/wp-includes/class-http.php on line 1218

I know what cron jobs are and I understand how WordPress might want to run periodic jobs (and since HTTP is stateless, running a "cron" job on the first request of the day makes sense) but why does it time out?

Comment: My first guess would be to check to make sure wp-cron.php is on your server.  Every time I upload WordPress, it times out in the transfer and I have to copy it over manually ...

Comment: Where are you hosting?  Sometimes hosts turn off HTTP callbacks.

Comment: It looks like wp-cron.php is in the root and I'd rather not say who the host is! I'll look though the faq and see if there is anything in there about HTTP callbacks.

Comment: There was nothing about HTTP callbacks (or wp-cron.php) in the faq just info about how they don't support cron jobs (which is why something like this exists in PHP, right?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a bug: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/11831

Comment: Lots of discussion on that link but it does describe the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I just ran into this same problem and found your answer. Thanks! @holizz.

Comment: For me it helps to repeat the request by clicking refresh. I only get the error message from time to time in my development environment.

Comment: @hakre: Once wp-cron has been requested, it isn't requested again for a certain period of time. Therefore, when you see the warning, you won't see it again for a short while. Also, the request frequently succeeds and thus doesn't cause a warning. Those two factors combine to make it only happen once in a while.